# Apply branches on multiple repositories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have a Rails app A and I cloned a Rails app B from it. Both have a separate Git repository for version control. Now I develop new features in separate feature branches which are then applied to either app A or app B.

But I also have feature or bug branches which need to be applied to both apps. Let's suppose I created a feature branch on app A and I want to apply this feature branch also to app B, how would I achieve this? Both git repo's are on my local machine and also on Github.

Comment: You can add `A` as a remote on `B` and pull the latest changes of former on `B`.

Comment: But then you are also add changes to B from A which you don't want to have in B, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new remote on B.

```
git remote add A <url of A>
```

Now you can pull in changes from `A` by running the following on `B` local:

```
git fetch A feature
git checkout -b feature A/feature
```

All you have to remember is to keep any changes which you want to share on a separate branch. Now suppose you got some undesirable changes on this branch which you do not want to merge. You can always cherry pick individual commits on top of your current branch (master?)

```
git co master
git cherry-pick <hash of commit>
```

You can read more about it here: http://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Using_Git_Cherry_Pick

Comment: Thanks, I will experiment with this.